# CalendarExtender stops working when i added the new AjaxControllToolkit

Tags: .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

CalendarExtender stops working when i added the new AjaxControllToolkit. I tested and it was working with

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server" EnablePartialRendering="true" ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" />
```

But i don't want to use `ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager`, does anyone know why it stop working and how can i make it work again only with `asp:ScriptManager`

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>    
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
             <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" CssClass="MyCalendar"
         PopupButtonID="imgCal1" TargetControlID="txtStartDate">
            </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <img  src="../../Images/imgdtpicker.png" id="imgCal1" runat="server" alt="" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what version of .NET is this running on?

Comment: @WimOmbelets: its argetFramework="4.0"